# Power BI Server returns HTTP Error 503 when configured on port 443

Tags: power-bi-report-server

I've a Power BI Server which is working OK on non-secure port 8001. I then installed a new certificate and try to use secure port 443 I get error - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
However, if I use some other port for ssl such as 8443 or 8500 it works and I can access reports. Switching back to 443 gives service unavailable error. There is no other application using port 443 on the server. I've run netstat -aon|findstr 443 and find no application using 443. There is no error in the event log either.

Any ideas will be much appreciated?

I've tried using other random ports for ssl and they work as expected.